# ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe in pipeline and columntransformer

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, pipeline

I am working on the toy dataset with `ColumnTransformer` and `pipeline` but I came across the error which I couldn't find a solution on the internet.

```py
toy = pd.read_csv('toy_dataset.csv')
toy_drop=toy.drop(['Number','Illness'],axis=1)
toy_target= toy.Illness
toy_target=toy_target.to_frame()
```

Data is imported:

```py
rb=RobustScaler()
normalization=MinMaxScaler()
ohe=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
le=LabelEncoder()
oe=OrdinalEncoder()
bins = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=5, encode='onehot-dense', strategy='uniform')

ct_features=ColumnTransformer([('normalization',normalization,['Income']),
                      ('ohe',ohe,['City','Gender','Illness']),
                      ('bins',bins,['Age']),
                      ],remainder='drop')


pip = Pipeline([
    ("ct",ct_features),
    #("collabel",ct_label),
    ('lr',LinearRegression())])

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(toy_drop,toy_target, test_size=0.2,random_state=2021)

pip.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

I think everything looks clear but this error:

```
ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe
```

occurred.

Comment: This is cause your 'Illness' column is no longer in `x_train` as you have dropped it in the above code here - `toy_drop=toy.drop(['Number','Illness'],axis=1)` which you later use for split.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shouldn’t it be that way? toy_drop corresponds features and toy_target corresponds labels so in train_test_split(X,y)

Comment: It is that way but in your case, you are using a pipeline that also does the preprocessing.

Comment: How can I split the dataset?

Comment: I don't think you need to `ohe` Illness so just remove it from `('ohe',ohe,['City','Gender','Illness'])`

Comment: It doesnot work... btw how can categorical variables are converted to numeric variable if I remove ohe?

Comment: you use 'LabelEncoder'. Try to make sense out of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkXEHpuu03A)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `remainder='drop'` in the `ColumnTransformer` write: `remainder='passthrough'`.

As you can see at
[sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html), by default, only the specified columns in transformers are transformed and combined in the output, and the non-specified columns are dropped. (default of 'drop'). By specifying remainder='passthrough', all remaining columns that were not specified in transformers will be automatically passed through